# Can repository return paging collections in DDD?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

It is possible to return a page object in a domain repository, such as a page findUsers(int page, int limit) method in a UserRepository.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should avoid querying your domain model.  Aggregates typically do not lend themselves to querying since they more-often-than-not represent some form of graph.  Quite a bit of your data may also be encapsulated and exposing that for the sake of querying may not be ideal.

I would suggest moving querying and, by extension, paging to a explicit query layer that returns the data in a form that makes sense.  I tend to use `I{AggregateName}Query` but you could name it whatever makes sense.  I could have the following methods:

```
public interface ICustomerQuery
{
    IEnumerable<Query.Customer> Search(Query.Customer.Specification specification);
    int Count(Query.Customer.Specification specification);
    Page<Query.Customer> Search(Query.Customer.Specification specification, int page);
}
```

Here I would have a namespace `Query` in my main namespace and that may contain *read models* that are plain data transfer objects (data containers) that contain only shape and no behaviour.  The `Customer` domain aggregate may very well contain a list of contacts and addresses that I do not want to hydrate just to show them in a list.  The `Query.Customer` read model, on the other hand, is a rather flat affair although you *may* choose to include something more complex for certain fetching strategies.  For instance:

```
namespace SomeProduct.Query
{
    public class Customer
    {
        Guid Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        string PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's so complicated to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Do you search something like that?

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

public interface UserRepository<User> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

    Page<User> findUsers(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: May I ask, in domain-driven design, can paging queries in the repository return aggregates or entities?